# how to transfer the item information to the next page?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

am listing all the items in my collection in the home page. This is the code

```
{{#each applications}}
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{previewImage}}" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                         <h4 class="pull-right">${{price}}</h4>
                         <h4><a href="#">{{title}}</a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>{{description}}</p>
                     </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

i have another template "itemDetails" which supposed to list the information of the item that the user click. How do i make the item clickable? and how do i transfer the user to the itemDetails with the information of the item that the user chose?

Comment: At least check the basic meteor documentation and example apps on their website. It has everything that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general setup which you should make in order to reach this effect.

> lib/router.js

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', function(){
    Session.set("itemId", this.params._id);
    this.render("navbar", {to:"navbar"});
    this.render("itemDetails", {to:"main"});
});
```

So now you have the route. Obviously the answer for the HTML is:

> HTML

```
<h4><a href="/item/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a>
```

In this way you have an unique route for each item, synchronized with the router's route.

And now finally when you pull a document from the database in your heelper for the `itemDetails` template use:

```
var itemId = Session.get("itemId");
```

Then use this id to find a document from the collection. And use the document properties to show in the HTML.